# experimental with hash lookup for IN clauses with many constants in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Wondering around https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.0/

- Allow hash lookup for IN clauses with many constants (James Coleman, David Rowley)

example `where empid in (1,2,3)`, Can I understand it this way:  PostgreSQL will hash `1`, `2`, `3` into 3 different hash value, then for each value, compare with table's hashup, if match then grap the matched row.

1. How do I know the query used **hash lookup** ?
2. Previously How does Postgresql do lookup for IN clause with many constants?
3. not that familiar with C,but want to see the code. Then I search git commit message https://prnt.sc/S15_5xc1cbBn, I cannot found relevant info, How can I search relevant info.

The following is QUERY PLAN for `explain analyze select * from emp where empid in (1,2,3);`

```
                                             QUERY PLAN -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Seq Scan on emp  (cost=0.00..1.12 rows=3 width=190) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=3 loops=1)
       Filter: (empid = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[]))
       Rows Removed by Filter: 4
     Planning Time: 1.054 ms
     Execution Time: 0.207 ms
    (5 rows)
```

Comment: Obviously a  table join would be faster. because I don't know what's normal lookup look like.

Comment: rows=3 and rows removed by filter: 4. Looks like you're testing on an (almost) empty table. A sequential scan will always be the fastest query plan.

Comment: @Mark: you can't always replace an IN condition with a JOIN - they are doing different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It easier to look into which tests are added with a feature to have an idea how it is working. Even though I did not find any benchmarks there are some regression test that gives an idea how this optimization working.

The related tests for this feature is in:

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/test/regress/sql/expressions.sql

The `MIN_ARRAY_SIZE_FOR_HASHED_SAOP` threshold is 9 so you can observe the effects with 9 elements. Even though the optimization is not visible in `explain` output you can see its effect with some experimentation.

```
CREATE TABLE ternary (a int NOT NULL, b text NOT NULL, c float);

INSERT INTO ternary(a, b, c)
SELECT i AS a, md5(i::text) AS b, log(i) AS c
FROM generate_series(1, 10000000, 1) AS i;

ANALYZE ternary;


create function return_text_input(text) returns text as $$
begin
    return $1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql stable;


set jit = off;                  
set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0;

explain analyze 
select return_text_input(t.b)  FROM ternary as t where t.b in 
(   '1b0fd9efa5279c4203b7c70233f86db', 
    '252e691406782824eec43d7eadc3d25', 
    'a8d2ec85eaf98407310b72eb73dda24',
    '74687a12d3915d3c4d83f1af7b3683d',
    '596a3d04481816330f07e4f97510c28',
    '47c1b025fa18ea96c33fbb6718688c0',
    '0267aaf632e87a63288a08331f22c7c',
    'b3149ecea4628efd23d2f86e5a72347'  ); 
-- 8 elements - Execution Time: 1007.018 ms in my machine


explain analyze 
select return_text_input(t.b)  FROM ternary as t where t.b in 
(   '1b0fd9efa5279c4203b7c70233f86db', 
    '252e691406782824eec43d7eadc3d25', 
    'a8d2ec85eaf98407310b72eb73dda24',
    '74687a12d3915d3c4d83f1af7b3683d',
    '596a3d04481816330f07e4f97510c28',
    '47c1b025fa18ea96c33fbb6718688c0',
    '0267aaf632e87a63288a08331f22c7c',
    'b3149ecea4628efd23d2f86e5a72347',
    '5d7b9adcbe1c629ec722529dd12e512' );
-- 9 elements - Execution Time: 611.685 ms   in my machine
```

As to how to be sure that the hash lookup is used in this case, I am not that familiar with postgresql maybe someone else can show an easy way to see it.